# JavaFx - Progress Bar does not show up

Tags: javafx

When I call my LoadingBar class from another class, the stage pops up but the actual bar does not.. what am I doing wrong? I also added where I call the class as well.

When I call my LoadingBar class from another class, the stage pops up but the actual bar does not.. what am I doing wrong? I also added where I call the class as well.

```
public class LoadingBar extends Stage {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    public LoadingBar() {
        progressBar = new ProgressBar(-1.0);

        setScene(new Scene(progressBar));
        setResizable(false);
        initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        show();
    }
}

public class JarParser {

    public enum JarTreeLevel {JAR, PACKAGE, CLASS, METHOD};

    private BottomUp bottomUp;
    private TreeItem<String> rootImport, rootPackage, rootClass, classMethod;
    private final Map<TreeItem<String>, JarTreeLevel> levelMap = new HashMap<TreeItem<String>, JarTreeLevel>();
    private String currentPackage, lastPackage, currentClass, currentClassFull, currentMethod;

    public JarParser(BottomUp bottomUp) {
        this.bottomUp = bottomUp;

        rootImport = new TreeItem<String>();
        levelMap.put(rootImport, JarTreeLevel.JAR);
    }

    public TreeItem<String> populateJarTree(JarFile jarFile) throws Exception {
        LoadingBar loadingBar = new LoadingBar();
        Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();

            String entryName = entry.getName();
            if (entryName.endsWith(".class")) {
                ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();

                InputStream classFileInputStream = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);
                try {
                    ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(classFileInputStream);
                    classReader.accept(classNode, 0);
                } finally {
                    classFileInputStream.close();
                }

                describeClass(classNode);
            }
        }
        loadingBar.close();
        return rootImport;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested and it works fine for me. Can you show the code where you call the `LoadingBar` constructor? In particular, is it being executed on the FX Application Thread?

Comment: I added the requested code

Answer (score 0):

You set the stage invisible?

```
public class LoadingBar extends Stage {

private ProgressBar progressBar;

public LoadingBar() {

    progressBar = new ProgressBar(-1.0);

    setScene(new Scene(progressBar));
    setResizable(false);
    initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);//?! delete this!
    show();
}
```

Comment: That sets the stage invisible not the contents of the stage

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your progress bar to a group and then adding the group to the scene:

```
Group group = new Group();
group.getChildren().add(progressBar);
setScene(new Scene(group));
...
```